# Marking / Highlighting range between two points on graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, graph

I was working with [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/features/key-features) for few days and one of the features i liked was the [Interactive timeline](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/features/key-features) (attached image from the linked video.),which allows us to interactively select/highlight data between two points using mouse move + drag. (time range in this case.)

[image: Highlighted graph.See the blue selection in the top half]

I was wondering if something similar exists using jquery/graphs/Html5 ?

[simile-widgets timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) seems to be the closest that i can find. But still not there.

What are the ways to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Highcharts / Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/) have this kind of zooming / marking feature built in. Have a look at [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) or [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) to get an idea. You will need to use their API to drill down to the points you need, but this depends a lot on your needs.